# TypeError: $(...).on is not a function $(document).on('click.alert.data-api', dismiss, Alert.prototype.close)

Tags: javascript, theming

I have installed a module to use less, so i installed a module [less css preprocessor](http://drupal.org/project/less). After enabling this module when i reload my home page i am getting an error and cant able to write any less,

Error Details:

```
 1."NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://seat3.nthq-136.com/PPI/Repo/WebSite/sites/default/files/less/5164124a1c0608.63828022/sites/all/themes/ppi/less/style.css?mkzncp" style.css?mkzncp

 2.TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
```

I have cleared my caches and uninstalled the above module and re installed  for several time but still the error appear .
Where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: You'll probably want to add more details of your installation into the question. For example, I assume you're using the Bootstrap theme? And haven't installed/configured jQuery Update to use jQuery 1.7?

Comment: should i need to install  jQuery Update module?

Comment: Not sure, you didn't mention if you're actually using Bootstrap or not ;) I think you are so I'd say yes, install jQuery update, then configure it to use jQuery 1.7. The `on()` method was only introduced in 1.7, that's the biggest give away here

Comment: Yes i am using Bootstrap and i recently installed jquery_update module but still it is not working .I have also tried this by flushing the less file and clearing the caches.

Comment: But have you ***configured*** the module?

Comment: Yes i have configured.

Comment: If you've got jQuery update installed, and configured properly to use v1.7, you won't get the 2nd error any more. Unless there are bugs in the Bootstrap code, but those will need to be reported to the module issue queue, we can't deal with them here I'm afraid. The first error is something different, you'll need to check your server logs to establish the underlying PHP error message. From there it should be reasonably simple to see where the problem is